# Is it possible to have different implementations for Phone and Desktop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conceptual

I understand that different layouts can be designed for Mobile Phones and Desktop Websites. But is it possible to implement two different approach implementations for Mobile Phones and Desktop.

For instance, is it possible to have one page designed as drag and drop for websites
and the same can be designed as, 
select stepwise for mobile phones.

Any clue or library or implementational approaches will be greatly appreciated. At the last, i am trying to implement the same website page in ReactJs.

Comment: I do not understand about some people. Was downgraded needed for this question? when i am asking for advice and having no clue, so how will i be having implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Platform specific code with different file extensions as follows

```
dragndrop.native.js//mobile platform
dragndrop.js//web platform
```

More info here [Platform React-Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#native-specific-extensions-ie-sharing-code-with-nodejs-and-web)